# How to send ref in Provider using React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-16

How to send ref in Provider using React Hook, ExampleRef.current return null? Should return a DOM element with id Example1

create Context

```
const ExampleContext = React.createContext({});
```

This is Provider

```
const ExampleProvider = ({
 children
}:{
 children: React$Node
}) => {
 const ExampleRef = useRef(null)

 return(
  <ExampleContext.Provider ref={ExampleRef} value={ExampleRef.current}>
   {children}
  </ExampleContext.Provider>
 );
};

class Example1 extends PureComponent<{...}> {
 static ExampleProvider: any
 static contextType = ExampleContext;

 render() {
  return(<div id={Example1}>...</div>)
 }
};

Object.assign(Example1, { ExampleProvider })
```

Using Provider

```
class Example2 extends PureComponent<{...}> {

 render() {
  return(
   <Example1.ExampleProvider>{...}<Example1.ExampleProvider>
  )
 }
};
```

If add DIV, ExampleRef.current returns the correct value, but I don't want to add DIV with another layer

```
return(
 <div ref={ExampleRef}>
  <ExampleContext.Provider value={ExampleRef.current}>
   {children}
  </ExampleContext.Provider>
 </div>
 );
```

Comment: Why are you passing Example1 as id without defining it?

Comment: You mean?:
return(<div id={Example1}>...</div>)

Comment: Yes, what you're trying to accomplish by this?

Comment: Example1 is a layer that covers the entire page. Based on example1, I want to place the layer with example2 on the page.
So it doesn't matter what example1 returns.